# How to set DateTime field as not required?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an entity with a DateTime property that is not required. When the form is submitted validation fails if this feld is left blank. I have set

```
ClientValidationEnabled = false
```

but validation still fails.

Comment: Make it a nullable DateTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set the field as nullable.

The `ClientValidationEnabled` is related to using JavaScript to validate the fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this thing by using two different way.

Either you can set that field as nullable or using jquery document.ready() method remove required attribute from that field.